# Analog of Kronecker's Theorem for Polynomials over an Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, extension-field

The usual  is stated something like this:

> **Kronecker's Theorem**: if $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ is a monic $n$-th order irreducible polynomial where $\mathbb{F}$ is a field then $\mathbb{F}[x]/(p(x))$ forms a degree $n$ extension field of $\mathbb{F}$. Moreover, if $\theta = x \ mod(p(x))$ then $\mathbb{F}[x]/(p(x))$ has basis $1, \theta, \dots , \theta^{n-1}$.

For example, $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \approxeq \mathbb{C}$. Indeed, if you survey any of the standard elementary abstract algebra texts you can find many theorems about such quotients. For example, see Theorem 4 of $\S 13.1$ of Dummit and Foote on page 513.

I'm studying certain questions involving polynomials over an **algebra**. Well, let's narrow it a bit. In this question I mean for $\mathcal{A}$ to denotes an $n$-dimensional, associative, commutative, unital algebra over the real numbers. I am hopeful the generalization of Kronecker's Theorem below holds true:

> **Kronecker's Theorem for Algebras:** If $p(x) \in \mathcal{A}[x]$ is a monic $n$-th order polynomial where $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra then $\mathcal{A}[x]/(p(x))$ forms a free $\mathcal{A}$-module of rank $n$. If we denote $\theta = x \ mod(p(x))$ we find basis $1, \theta, \dots , \theta^{n-1}$ for $\mathcal{A}[x]/(p(x))$.

I've read the proof of the usual theorem in Dummit and Foote and it appears it adapts to prove "Kronecker's Theorem for Algebras" as detailed above.

> **Question:** is my assertion correct? Is "Kronecker's Theorem for Algebras" true? Or, can you provide evidence to the contrary?

I thank the MSE in advance for your insights!
(I put the extension field tag because this question is closely related to that arena of thought)

Comment: This is true but it's not a generalization of Kronecker's theorem (no mention of irreducibility, and Kronecker's theorem does not need the hypothesis that $p$ is monic).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Glad you saw this! Does it have a name, or is this too basic to have a name?

Comment: I'm not aware of it having a name (I wasn't even aware of Kronecker's theorem having a name). Also, you really only need $A$ to be a commutative ring in the statement.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks for the comments. Incidentally, I just posted a related and considerably more specific question which is related to this one:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2366351/a-particular-quotient-of-polynomials-over-hyperbolic-numbers-is-it-anything it might be interesting...