# A Particular Quotient of Polynomials over Hyperbolic Numbers: is it Anything?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, hypercomplex-numbers, split-complex-numbers

The **hyperbolic numbers** are a two real dimensional algebra generated by $j$ such that $j^2=1$. In particular, denote $\mathcal{H} = \{ a+bj \ | \ a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Multiplication is done in the natural manner,
$$ (a+bj)(x+jy) = ax+by+j(bx+ay) $$
and we may establish that $\mathcal{H}$ is an associative, unital, commutative algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. Consider $\mathcal{A}' = \mathcal{H}[x]/\langle x^2-(1+j)x+j \rangle$ where $\mathcal{H}[x]$ denotes the ring of polynomials in $x$ with hyperbolic number coefficients. The quotient has arithmetic defined in the usual fashion; add and multiply modulo $\mathcal{H}[x]$ multiples of $x^2-(1+j)x+j$.

At first I had hoped $\mathcal{A}' \approxeq \mathcal{H} \times \mathcal{H}$ (as a direct product), but, after some thought I think my first thought is wrong. 
I don't think $\langle x-1 \rangle $ and $\langle x-j \rangle$ are comaximal, and, I suspect that suffices to deny my initial guess.

> **Question:** is there a better way to look at $\mathcal{A}' = \mathcal{H}[x]/\langle x^2-(1+j)x+j \rangle$ ?

In other words, can we see this as some sort of semi-direct product of copies of $\mathcal{H}$ etc. ?

Incidentally, this particular quotient is interesting since $x^2-(1+j)x+j = (x-1)(x-j)$ and $1-j$ is a zero divisor of $\mathcal{H}$. Thanks in advance for your insights into this problem!

Comment: Given the conjecture of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2366212/36530 I expect $\mathcal{A}'$ is a rank $2$ $\mathcal{H}$-module which means it should form a four dimensional real algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call the hyperbolic numbers, I call split complex numbers. In any case, CRT proffers an isomorphism (of rings / real vector spaces)

$$ \mathbb{R}[j] = \frac{\mathbb{R}[T]}{(T^2-1)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{R}[T]}{(T-1)}\oplus\frac{\mathbb{R}[T]}{(T+1)}\cong\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}. $$

The elements corresponding to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ must be idempotents that sum to unity; solving the equation $(a+bj)^2=a+bj$ yields $(1\pm j)/2$ as our idempotents. Thus we have

$$ \begin{array}{cc} \displaystyle \frac{1+j}{2}\leftrightarrow (1,0) & \quad & 1\leftrightarrow (1,1)~~~ \\[5pt] \displaystyle \frac{1-j}{2} \leftrightarrow (0,1) & \quad &  j\leftrightarrow (1,-1) \end{array} $$

There is also an isomorphism $(\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R})[x]\cong \mathbb{R}[x]\oplus \mathbb{R}[x]$. Consider the problem of quotienting this ring by the principal ideal generated by the tuple $(p(x),q(x))$. We can multiply the generator by the idempotents $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ to obtain $(p(x),0)$ and $(0,q(x))$ in the ideal, and conversely we can obtain the original tuple as the sum of these, so

$$ \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]\oplus\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle \,(p(x),q(x))\,\rangle}=\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]\oplus\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle\, (p(x),0), \, (0,q(x))\, \rangle} \cong \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle p(x)\rangle} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle q(x)\rangle}.$$

In your case, the principal generator is $((x-1)^2,x^2-1)$, so the resulting ring is

$$ \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle (x-1)^2\rangle} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{\langle x^2-1\rangle}. $$

The first summand is an isomorphic copy of the dual numbers $\mathbb{R}[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$ and the second summand is another copy of the hyperbolic numbers / split complex numbers.

We can interpret this decomposition as one of modules over the split complex numbers $\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}$ by interpreting the first summand as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}\oplus 0$ and the second as a vector space over $0\oplus\mathbb{R}$ (and in which $0\oplus\mathbb{R}$ annihilates the first summand and $\mathbb{R}\oplus 0$ annihilates the second). In particular, the second summand is not a copy of the regular representation as a module, even though it is a copy of the split complex numbers as a ring and vector space.

Comment: Well, this is more than I hoped for. Now I just need to take your insight and come up with the explicit isomorphism from $\mathcal{A}'$ to pairs of the form $(a+b\varepsilon, c+dj)$ where $\varepsilon^2=0$ and $j^2=1$. Thanks much for this, it certainly answers my question.

Comment: If you look at the Wikipedia article, you'll find something like a dozen different names for these things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number (see Synonyms)

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Yes, I am aware it has many names. I like them to be alongside split quaternions and split octonions personally, although of course the split complex numbers involve hyperbolic trig functions the same way complex numbers involve trig functions. Anyway, since $a+bj=(a+b)\frac{1+j}{2}+(a-b)\frac{1-j}{2}$, the explicit isomorphism to $\Bbb R[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)\oplus{\cal H}$ is just $$a(x)+b(x)j\mapsto (a(\epsilon+1)+b(\epsilon+1),a(j)-b(j))$$ (where we identify residue classes with their representatives for notational convenience).

Comment: I see, those are polynomial evaluations.

Comment: Yes. In the first summand , $x-1\leftrightarrow\varepsilon$, and in the second summand, $x\leftrightarrow j$.

Comment: Well, that makes a lot a sense. Shame on me for not trying that already!

Comment: Incidentally, I've got a few papers in this realm I'd like to publish somewhere, do you happen to have a suggestion on where a good place to communicate this sort of math might be.

Comment: Nope. ${}{}{}{}$